# Check email validation and input fields are inserted

Tags: jquery

Im trying to create registration wizard which checks if any field is empty and email is valid.

If first page has inputs:

> Name
>
> Phone number
>
> Email

and second page has inputs:

> Business name
>
> Phone number
>
> Email

It must check first these validation before allows to return second page.

My code:

```
function IsEmail(email) {
    var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-\+])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    if(!regex.test(email)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

/*
    Form
*/
$('.f1 fieldset:first').fadeIn('slow');

$('.f1 input[type="text"], .f1 input[type="password"], .f1 input[type="email"], .f1 textarea').on('focus', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('input-error');
});

// next step
$('.f1 .btn-next').on('click', function() {
    var parent_fieldset = $(this).parents('fieldset');
    var next_step = true;
    // navigation steps / progress steps
    var current_active_step = $(this).parents('.f1').find('.f1-step.active');
    var progress_line = $(this).parents('.f1').find('.f1-progress-line');

    // fields validation    
    console.log($('input[type="text"]').val() + $('input[type="password"]').val() + $('input[type="email"]').val());
    parent_fieldset.find('input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="email"], textarea').each(function() {
        if( $(this).val() == "") {
            $(this).addClass('input-error');
            next_step = false;
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('input-error');
        }
    });

    parent_fieldset.find('input[type="email"]', function() {
        if( IsEmail('input[type="email"]') == false) {
            $('input[type="email"]').addClass('input-error');
            next_step = false;
        } else {
            $('input[type="email"]').removeClass('input-error');
        }
    });
    // fields validation

    if( next_step ) {
        parent_fieldset.fadeOut(400, function() {
            // change icons
            current_active_step.removeClass('active').addClass('activated').next().addClass('active');
            // progress bar
            bar_progress(progress_line, 'right');
            // show next step
            $(this).next().fadeIn();
            // scroll window to beginning of the form
            scroll_to_class( $('.f1'), 20 );
        });
    }

});
```

---

Problem: input and email validation doesnt work, it lets click "next" button and shows second page (wizard form).

Comment: Your function check for the email value not for object .. `IsEmail($('input[type="email"]).val()) === false` .. this if statement I'm sure its right .. But by using it inside `parent_fieldset.find('input[type="email"]' , function(){ ...` I don't know it will work or not .. So I prefer to define `var email_input = parent_fieldset.find('input[type="email"]');` and same thing for password then use `if(IsEmail(email_input.val()) === false)`

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef Make answer for my post and I accept as best answer. Your code worked!